# How to read the contents in a <div> element, using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
app.post('/uploadfile_submitted', function(req,res){
   console.dir(req.files);
   res.render('uploadfile_submitted', {name: req.body.name});
})
```

I use the above code to read the contents of a form. Now if i were to have div elements in my html body how would i access that text content.

Comment: Create a hidden field in the form and set the value of it to the contents of the div.

Comment: why do you need that for? if you need the data in the server side - send it (either by `hidden` input or by adding parameter to AJAX request). if you need it in the client side - no need to travel to the server for that

Answer (score 0):

You don't need node.js, simply using `element.innerHTML` would access the HTML element's innerHTML. e.g. `var value = document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML;`